# How to create a sbt plugin that reuses includeFilter key?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, protocol-buffers

I am creating a [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) plugin for Sbt.

I created a new `TaskKey` named `protoc` to convert `.proto` files to `.java` files.

```
val protoc = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("protoc", "Convert proto to java.")
```

I also injected my `protoc` task to `sbt.Keys.sourceGenerators`:

```
sourceGenerators <+= protoc
```

As [Plugins Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#reuse-existing-keys) said, I reused SBT's existing `sbt.Keys.sources` to indicate the source `.proto` files. I wrote some code equivalent to these:

```
// To generate .java from main .proto
protoc in Compile <<= (sources in protoc in Compile, ...) map { (protoSources, ...) =>
  ...
}

// To generate .java from test .proto
protoc in Test <<= (sources in protoc in Test, ...) map { (protoSources, ...) =>
  ...
}
```

The problem occured while I was trying to reuse `sbt.Keys.includeFilter`. I tried this:

```
// For test protos being compiled
includeFilter in unmanagedSources in protoc in Test := "*.proto"

// For test protos being included
includeFilter in ProtobufKeys.unmanagedInclude in protoc in Test := "*.proto"
```

It did not work, because `in protoc` would cover `in unmanagedSources`!

How can I create a code generator plugin that conforms the "Reuse existing keys" rule?

Comment: Note that there is an existing sbt plugin for protobuf that you might consider contributing to: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf.

Comment: Can you explain the need to scope includeFilter by both unmanagedSources and protoc and not simply protoc?

Comment: Because I have another custom Key `unmanagedInclude`

Comment: It isn't possible to have multiple tasks like `in unmanagedSources in protoc` and I don't see that changing.  So, you could do `includeFilter in protoc` in the first case and `includeFilter in ProtobufKeys.unmanagedInclude` in the second.  The "Reuse existing keys" rule is intended to be a guideline that you might have to break here.  However, you might also question whether it is really necessary to separately configure includeFilter for both of those.

Comment: How about creating some other configurations, e.g. compile-protobuf test-protobuf, which groups settings for protoc? If I have custom configurations, I think I don't need `in protoc` any more.

Comment: A configuration groups related settings and files within a project.  For test sources, files, and tasks, there is Test.  In your case, protobuf sources and generated files would typically be attached to another configuration, like Compile or Test.